# how to execute compound commands in shell script?

Tags: shell-script, diff, command-substitution

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/sh

result=$((diff <(sort 1.txt) <(sort 2.txt)))
if [[ $result != "" ]]
then
    echo ERROR
else
    echo PASS
fi
```

I got an error when execute this script:

```
chk.sh: line 3: diff <(sort 1.txt) <(sort 2.txt): missing `)' (error token is "1.txt) <(sort 2.txt)")
```

What the reason and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few points:

- process substitution (`<( ... )`) and the extended test syntax `[[ ... ]]` is not available in sh. You need more advanced shells like bash or ksh for those.
- `$(( ... ))` is arithmetic substitution, not command substitution. You need `$( ... )` here.
- Instead of checking the output of `diff`, you can check the exit status of `diff` directly in the `if` condition. You can discard the unused output. (So you don't even need command substitution or `[[ ... ]]` here.)

And suggestions from the comments:

- You can avoid negating the condition in `if` by swapping the `if` and `else` blocks
- You can use the just-as-efficient `cmp -s` command if all you want to do is check if the files are different.

Combined:

```
#!/bin/bash

if cmp -s <(sort 1.txt) <(sort 2.txt)
then
    echo PASS
else
    echo ERROR
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, added both suggestions. Any ideas on avoiding the process substitution without temp files?

Comment: Thanks~ But still, I got an error : chk.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('    It seems " <( " can't be used?

Comment: Did you change the first line to bash? You're not on a Mac, are you?

Comment: I found the command is still sh, not bash, bash is ok :)